# Unable to communicate between client and server

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

**My server program**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MultiServe implements Runnable 
{
    static ServerSocket ss;
    static Socket s;
    public void run()
    {
        String name=Thread.currentThread().getName();
        for(;;)
        {   

            try
            {
                System.out.println("thread:"+name+"ready to accept");
                s=ss.accept();
                System.out.println("thread:"+name+" accepted");
                PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
                ps.println("Thread"+name+"contacted You");
                String sz,str1;             
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                BufferedReader bk=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                while(true)
                {
                while((sz=br.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    System.out.println(sz);
                    str1=bk.readLine();
                    ps.close();
                    br.close();
                    bk.close();
                    s.close();
                }
                }

            }catch(Exception e){}

        }       
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        MultiServe ms=new MultiServe();
        ss=new ServerSocket(8080);
        Thread t=new Thread(ms,"one");
        Thread t1=new Thread(ms,"two");
        t.start();
        t1.start();



    }
}
```

**My client program**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MultiClient
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        Socket s=new Socket("localhost",8080);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String str,str1;
        DataOutputStream ds=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader bk=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while(!(str=bk.readLine()).equals("exit"))
        {
            ds.writeBytes(str+"\n");
            str1=br.readLine();
            System.out.println(str1);
        }
        ds.close();
        bk.close();
        br.close();
        s.close();
    }
}
```

New to socket programming but I am able to connect but unable to communicate. I dont know whether it has reached a deadlock. Both are connecting but they are not receiving any messages.

Comment: Suggestion, don't swallow exceptions. if you look at your code you read the line then immediately close ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your try catch block.. there must be some error inside the try block. You have two threads waiting on the same socket. when someone connects both are trying to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect.

1. You are running two threads on the same socket.
2. `writeBytes(String)` method of the `DataOutputStream` in your client writes the string as an array of byte, where as the `readLine()` method of `BufferedReader` on the server expects a line of text. Here you can use `PrintStream` in the client, instead.
3. You cannot close the stream, on the server after every read, if you want to continue reading on this socket.
4. If you are reading a line on the client, you need to write something from the server, as well.

Try the following code to achieve the desired effect:

**Server:**

```
public class Server implements Runnable 
{
    static ServerSocket ss;
    static Socket s;
    public void run()
    {
        String name=Thread.currentThread().getName();
        for(;;)
        {   

            try
            {
                System.out.println("thread:"+name+"ready to accept");
                s=ss.accept();
                System.out.println("thread:"+name+" accepted");
                PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
                ps.println("Thread"+name+"contacted You");
                String sz,str1;             
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                BufferedReader bk=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                while((sz=br.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    System.out.print(sz+"\nYour Msg:");
                    str1=bk.readLine();
                    ps.println(str1);

                }
                ps.close();
                br.close();
                bk.close();
                s.close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }       
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
       Server ms=new Server();
        ss=new ServerSocket(8080);
        Thread t=new Thread(ms,"one");
        //Thread t1=new Thread(ms,"two");
        t.start();
        //t1.start();



    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
public class Client
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        Socket s=new Socket("localhost",8080);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String str,str1;
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader bk=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print(br.readLine()+"\nEnter:");
        while(!(str=bk.readLine()).equals("exit"))
        {
            ps.println(str);

            str1=br.readLine();
            System.out.print(str1+"\nEnter:");
        }
        ps.close();
        bk.close();
        br.close();
        s.close();
    }
}
```